# Docker Hub login behind a proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I recently installed Docker 18.04.0-ce on my Ubuntu 17.10 VM. While working behind a proxy I got stuck trying to log in into the Docker Hub registry. So when I run:

```
docker login -u <username> -p <cool password>
```

And I get this message:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http:  
request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while 
awaiting headers)
```

As far as my understanding goes from the research I did is that when you are behind a proxy and you want to use Docker you need to configure it accordingly even though having set your environment variable like so:

```
http_proxy=<my_proxy>
https_proxy=<my_proxy>
HTTP_PROXY=<my_proxy>
HTTPS_PROXY=<my_proxy>
```

Second, it looks like that Docker has multiple levels of proxy configurations meaning different configuration for build, containers, and the daemon.

I went and configured all of those to match my proxy, but I still get that message. YES, I DID RESTART the service and the daemon.

**UPDATE:**

```
$ docker info

Containers: 8
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 8
Images: 12
Server Version: 18.04.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-39-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 17.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 7.79GiB
Name: docker-vb
ID: 447I:6DFI:JZ7V:F6SZ:BUCB:IFB2:4HGT:MXK2:Y5H5:EECC:FIQN:SZOH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: http://<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
HTTPS Proxy: http://<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Where did you set the variables, and how did you verify that the engine is using those settings? Did you check `docker info`? How is docker being run (e.g. systemd)?

Comment: @BMitch I have updated the post with my docker info output. ps tells me that dockerd runs as a service so it is started from from systemd.

Comment: @BMitch Could that error originate from the DNS not resolving the host name registry-1.docker.io ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docker login typically needs to be run with sudo priviledges, so ensure that the HTTPS_PROXY environment is actually preserved. Simply done by

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=<your proxy>
```

Or simply pass it on the command line:

```
sudo HTTPS_PROXY=<your proxy> docker login -u <user> <registry>
```

The docker daemon doesn't need to be restarted.
The above works fine (we use extensivelye proxies at work).

There may be some issues with your network reachability, proxy, and possibly the registry. The docker log can provide some clues:

Ubuntu: `sudo journalctl -fu docker.service`

RHEL: `/var/log/messages | grep docker`

Comment: you are my savior and i had lost all hope.

Comment: How to do it without sudo? If Im in situation where I can't use sudo, then what is the alternative?

Comment: Are you able to run docker without sudo? If so, then simply passing the HTTPS_PROXY=<your proxy> on the command line, or setting your env will do.
Generally, docker requires elevated privileges to be run.

Comment: I have http(s)_proxy as well as HTTP(S)_PROXY set and many other applications work fine with them, but not Docker login. Setting the username, password, and proxy address in the http-proxy.config file does work. So the credentials and URL appears fine. But putting your credentials in plain text in a file like that does not feel... OK.
I'm on Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3