# How to use "docker login" with a proxy?

Tags: docker, proxy

I am trying to run `docker login`, but I am getting the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://[removed_id_for_stackoverflow].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have the following within my `~/.bash.rc` file:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://192.168.1.1:8080"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://192.168.1.1:8080"
export https_proxy="http://192.168.1.1:8080"
export https_proxy="http://192.168.1.1:8080"
export ftp_proxy="http://192.168.1.1:8080"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

If I run `curl https://www.google.com` then I can get a valid response, confirming that these settings work. If I remove these environment variables, then my `curl` command no longer works, so I'm pretty sure it's configured correctly from an environment variable perspective.

According to [Docker Hub login behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045082/docker-hub-login-behind-a-proxy), you can just pass the proxy options into the command line when running `docker login`; however, I've tried this and the results are the same. See the example below:

```
root@my-host:~/.docker# HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.1:8080 aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account').dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com >/dev/null
Error response from daemon: Get "https://[removed_for_stack_overflow].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I tried changing the proxy settings to appear before `docker login` instead of `aws`, tried using `HTTP_PROXY` instead of `HTTPS_PROXY`,  but still no luck. Doesn't seem to matter in which order the proxy options are specified.

I also have a file called `~/.docker/config.json` that contains the following proxy information:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.1:8080",
     "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.1:8080"
   }
 }
}
```

Even with this setting, docker login doesn't appear to be working still and provides the same results.

Comment: http://pahlevanzadeh.net/docker-pull-%d9%88-systemd-%d9%85%d8%b4%da%a9%d9%84-%da%a9%d8%b4%d9%88%d8%b1%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%ab%d9%84-%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%86/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way to configure proxy for docker daemon is recorded [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy), I extract some of contents for your infomation:

> 1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:
>
>    `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
> 2. Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable:
>
>    Config example:
>
>    ```
>    [Service]
>    Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
>    Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443"
>    Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp"
>    ```
> 3. Flush changes and restart Docker
>
>    ```
>    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>    sudo systemctl restart docker
>    ```
> 4. Verify that the configuration has been loaded and matches the changes you made, for example:
>
>    `sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker`

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. The daemon proxy settings are set and configured properly (as per your step 4), but the `docker login` command still times out and doesn't seem to use the proxy. I don't think the docker dameon.

Comment: Change to a wrong proxy e.g. `http://proxy.example.com:80`, there should be next error: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com: no such host`, this just to prove you really set it correctly with a fake proxy as you can see from the log it tries to proxyconnect to the proxy at the first stage. And what does timeout mean? Any error here? And any hardware firewall before your pc? Any iptables block the output connection?

Comment: Just set the proxy to random characters to see if it'd have some DNS resolution errors, but still no luck with the `docker login` command. In fact, it doesn't time out anymore, it just hangs, but I should have mentioned it was doing that before I configured the proxy as well. I can use other commands such as `cURL` and stuff with no problems, so I have a feeling the proxy settings are correct, but perhaps docker login just doesn't like using a proxy? No IP tables, firewall, etc.

Comment: So weird. Seems to be working fine just now after reproducing the same steps again. Thanks a lot for the help. Not sure why it choked up the first time.

Answer (score 0):

atline's approach is correct.
But I my environment with a proxy with username/pw I was not successfull, whatever I tried.

Finally following steps did the tick:

- Configure the proxy like atline wrote *but* without username/pw
- Configure your proxy in your shell/system (with username/pw), so you can use `curl` e.g. `curl stackoverflow.com` passing the proxy
- then start your docker-workload (im my case `docker-compose up`)
- connection shoud suddly be possible

during longer workloads it can be neccessary to do the curl-trick in a separate terminal (maybe you can script and trigger the curl periodicaly).

It seems that proxies cache the login for a while.